# GPA Calculator not Returning Corresponding Grades

Tags: c++, c, gpa

I'm trying to calculate a student's GPA in C programming language with the code below but it's not returning the correct corresponding grade based on each score, feels like it just picks a random letter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

float gpa_ICT(int a){

    float point[a], unit[a], score[a];
    char C_code[12][6][a];
    char grade[a];

//Read Course code, score and unit
    for(int x = 0; x < a; x++){
        printf("Enter Course Code: ");
        scanf("%6s", &C_code[x]);
        printf("Enter course score: ");
        scanf("%f", &score[x]);
        printf("Enter course unit: ");
        scanf("%f", &unit[x]);

        //Assign values to Course point and Grade based on Score.
        if(score[x] >= 70){
            grade[x]= "A";
            point[x] = 5;
        }
        else if (score[x] >= 60 && score[x] <=69){
            grade[x]= "B";
            point[x] = 4;
        }
        else if (score[x] >= 50 && score[x] <=59){
            grade[x]= "C";
            point[x] = 3;
        }
        else if (score[x] >= 45 && score[x] <=49){
            grade[x]= "D";
            point[x] = 2;
        }
        else if (score[x] <=44){
            grade[x]= "F";
            point[x] = 0;
        }
        else{
           printf("ERROR!");
        }
    }


//Check score for each course
//Return the Course Code and grade based on score
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
        printf("%s : %c\n",C_code[i] ,grade[i]);
    }

//Multiply each point by corresponding course unit and sum them up
    float sum = 0;
    float Total;
    for(int y = 0; y < a; y++){
        Total = point[y]*unit[y];
        sum = sum + Total;
    }

//Calculate the total Course unit
    float totalUnit = 0;
    for(int z = 0; z < a; z++){
        totalUnit = totalUnit + unit[z];
    }

    //Calculate the GPA
    float GPA = sum / totalUnit;

    return GPA;
}

int main()
{
    int course;
    printf("How many courses? ");
    scanf("%d", &course);


    float result = gpa_ICT(course);
    printf("Your GPA is %0.2f", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output
**How many courses? 3**

**Enter Course Code: MTS202**

**Enter course score: 75**

**Enter course unit: 3**

**Enter Course Code: ICT202**

**Enter course score: 58**

**Enter course unit: 2**

**Enter Course Code: MEE202**

**Enter course score: 65**

**Enter course unit: 2**

**MTS202 : D**

**ICT202 : H**

**MEE202 : F**

**Your GPA is 4.14**

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 32.212 s
Press any key to continue.**

Comment: First thing I noticed was that you are setting ```grade[x] = "A"``` the double quotes signifiy a string or char*, not char. Replace the double quites with single quotes, 'A';

Comment: And if your compiler didn't warn you about that, it's time to turn on warnings, or get a better compiler, if you can.

Comment: it seems like that was your issue, the letters should be printing correctly now.

Comment: Only bring this up because it can prove really important: `"A"` will be a `const` `char` array, specifically `const char[2]`. It will decay to a `const char *`. The `const` can get you, and knowing that it's really an array can be used to save you a bundle of time and code.

Comment: The above points are all valid, but I also want to point out that you have created `C_code` as a *three*-dimensional array, when I suspect what you realy want is a two-dimensional one. I think you want `char C_code[a][7];`

Comment: Please be aware that your students need to attent different classes for C and C++. Same goes for your question. C and C++ are different languages and you should decide which language you want to use. As long as you don't mix them you should not tag both languages but only pick the relevant one.